# Is there a way to take an image file and make its background transparent via VB .NET?

Tags: vb.net, image

We have a system where people are being taken a face shot via a DSLR camera. We need the people's images with transparent background. What we're currently doing is taking the image and editing and cropping it in Photoshop, removing the background image with the Magic Eraser tool.

What I am looking for is a way to parse the image and automatically erase the semi-white background we have, along with the resizing and cropping. Is there some kind of library or code sample that does this without requiring manual intervention?

Comment: Never use it but I think this is a good starting point: [Bitmap.MakeTransparent Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.drawing.bitmap.maketransparent.aspx).

Comment: Finding a library that can manipulate an image to be transparent and cropped and resized will be easy. I prefer [The FreeImage Project](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net). But writing the AI that knows what to make transparent, especially when it comes to hair, will be a pain in the assuming you can formulate rules for it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a real complex problem. Like the answer below suggested you'll need to do a fuzzy match on each pixel and set it to be transparent but you also need to detected other nearby pixels to make sure they are not close in color. A white tag on the shirt, white eyelids, hair, pale skin reflecting the flash. All are candidates to be removed by any greedy fuzzy logic.

Think about the Magic Wand tool in Photoshop. How good is it at detecting the edges of the person in the picture? Yeah, and that's the top standard of image editing software with thousands of engineering hours behind it.

This is not a feasible request for a Q&A format, and this is one of those things that humans just do better than machine. BUT, that doesn't mean it's not possible, and who knows, you might be the one to do it. Just don't do it in VB.NET please :)

Some pseudo-code to get an idea of what you need to do:

```
Bitmap faceShot = Bitmap.FromFile(filepath)
foreach pixel in faceShot
    //the following line is where the magic happens, you can do any fuzzy match on the color that suits you
    //figure out your color range and do a fuzzy match percentage wise
    if (pixel between RGB(255,255,255) and RGB(250,235,215)) //white and antique white
        pixel.setAlpha=0
    endif
end foreach
```

Comment: Small disclaimer: You can use VB.NET, I have nothing against it. I just wanted to lighten up the tone of the post.

If a fuzzy match is all you need, by all means Kratz's answer is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with this as a starting point for processing a single image,

http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/2D/ProcessanImageinvertPixel.htm

Basically, if you have a constant background color (like the TV green-screen), it's just a matter of selecting pixels close to the color you are erasing and setting their Alpha level to 0 (transparent). Treating the RGB values like XYZ coordinates, you can do a 3d distance from your background color, and make everything within a certain threshold transparent.

As an improvement, you could also make everything within another threshold semi-transparent so the edges right around hair and stuff like that look softer and less harsh.

Alternatively, you could probably do the same exact thing with good results in Photoshop, as it should support batch processing.

Edit, thinking about it some more, you may want to use a green screen type background as well instead of an off-white one like you stated, as you may make people's eyes transparent. I would definitely try to batch it in Photoshop/Gimp/etc.